# is it possible to return previous .xib file in objective c?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i have two .xib file like a.xib and b.xib. Now i am in b.xib file from a.xib by using a button action like bellow:

```
loginVController = [[a alloc]initWithNibName:@"a" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:loginVController animated:YES];
```

Now is it possible to return on a.xib file from b,xib file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, by :

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Comment: But it is not working properly. I have used just above code on back button action? like -(IBaction)back:(id)sender{ [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated];}

Comment: Finally i have got it [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

Answer (score 0):

You can simply dismiss the presentmodalViewController(b.xib) to see the viewController with nib file a.xib, if you present the b.xb from a.xib